Textbox focus moving strangely in multipage VBA Userforms
I have a multipage form that I want to use for setup for a data analysis macro. I want some textboxes to show a warning label if the user exits them without entering a valid value, so I used the textbox_exit() event to set the label to visible if the textbox doesn't contain a valid value. The issue is that the focus always starts on the tab of the multipage, but whenever I click on a textbox, the focus always goes to one particular textbox for a moment before moving to the textbox I selected. The focus goes to the textbox I created first, regardless of name, position on the multipage or location of its code in the program. This sets off the warning label for that textbox, which I don't want to have happening.
I reproduced it as simply as possible, here's the code:

Option Explicit
Dim Cancel As Boolean

Private Sub Textbox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox1 > 5 And TextBox1 < 10 Then
        Label1.Visible = False
    Else
        Label1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Textbox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox2 > 5 And TextBox2 < 10 Then
        Label2.Visible = False
    Else
        Label2.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Everything is on a multipage with two pages. The second one is empty. The first one has three textboxes and two labels. When I click on either of the other two boxes, the box that I made first focuses for a second and its warning label pops up.
Is there a way to get the focus to move directly, or is this just a fact of how VBA treats multipages? If so, any suggestions for another way to make this form?

You know you can add a line If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) = 0 Then Exit Sub right after Private Sub Textbox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)? This will not trigger the label.

That does work, thanks! I'm going to leave this up in case someone can explain the underlying situation, but many thanks

I am willing to help but I am unable to reproduce the above issue. Can you create a sample file and share the link here after uploading it to any free file loading site?

I hope this worked? Let me know if you can't access the files. I also included a screen recording of it doing it. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ErAuB76sEC4_evVOTjN3xeC2ZEuqRUIy?usp=sharing
